# AKS Get Access Profile In Java

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I need to programmatically get the access profile for an AKS cluster from Java. I see that the REST API to do this is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/getaccessprofile). Is this API exposed in the azure java sdk? If so where? If not, I would have to use an http client and add the Bearer token in the header. But, how could I use the azure sdk to programmatically get a Bearer token for a particular client id and client secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, maybe you can get AKS cluster access profile use the Java SDK [`userKubeConfigContent()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-containerservice/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/containerservice/implementation/KubernetesClusterImpl.java#L84).

And you also can get the access token in the Java Code. See [get the access token](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headless#about-the-code). And the code will like this:

```
// Request access token from AAD
AuthenticationResult result = getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(
                    username, password);
// Get user info from Microsoft Graph
String userInfo = getUserInfoFromGraph(result.getAccessToken());
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! These are exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful:-)